# render a SINGLE GSP in a specific locale

Tags: grails, internationalization, locale, gsp

I'm trying to render a GSP in a specific locale.

Both these solutions work

using params

```
    /book/list?lang=es
```

Using code in controller

```
    def newLocale = new Locale(lang)
    RCU.getLocaleResolver(request).setLocale(request, response, newLocale)
    render(view: "mail", model: [invoiceInstance: invoiceInstance])
```

Unfortunately both these solution change the session object forever and affects all GSP afterwards.

If I try the change the LocaleResolver after the Render statement it does not work.

```
    // Switch to OWNER language for print preview
    def newLocale = new Locale(lang)
    RCU.getLocaleResolver(request).setLocale(request, response, newLocale)

    render(view: "mail", model: [invoiceInstance: invoiceInstance])

    // switch back to user language
    def newLocale2 = new Locale(user.language)
    RCU.getLocaleResolver(request).setLocale(request, response, newLocale2)
```

So how can a force a SINGLE render in a specific locale?

Comment: Are you trying to change the locale to use in <g:message/>?

Comment: No. I'm trying to render a full GSP in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much search I had to pass the locale object to every  tags in the GSP.

Not elegant for Grails but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think your second try can work if you use the new [Page Rendering API](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#webFeatures) at the place of renderer.

```
    // Switch to OWNER language for print preview
    def newLocale = new Locale(lang)
    RCU.getLocaleResolver(request).setLocale(request, response, newLocale)

    def contents = groovyPageRenderer.render(view:"/controller/mail", model: [invoiceInstance: invoiceInstance])

    // switch back to user language
    def newLocale2 = new Locale(user.language)
    RCU.getLocaleResolver(request).setLocale(request, response, newLocale2)

    render contents
```

Comment: pageRenderer does not seem to respond  to setLocale which I think is session based. Maybe if I can find how to change locale of AppContext ?

Comment: @StéphaneRainville if you print RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request) inside your gsp, what's the result?

Comment: If I try print 
 value="${session.'org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE' I get an error because the session is not supported in pageRenderer


 value="${org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request)}" always get en_CA which is the browser setting I think

Comment: Hmmm I see, strange... I'll post the question to grails forum... Im interested in it too...